# I was trying to run MySQL query using Python but getting error 1064 (42000):

Tags: python, mysql, jupyter-notebook

```
import mysql.connector as connection

try:
    mydb = connection.connect(host="localhost", database = 'motogp',user="root", passwd="unlock24708651",use_pure=True)
    # check if the connection is established
    print(mydb.is_connected())

    query = "CREATE TABLE Riders_championship(Rank INT(3), Rider_name CHAR(20), Nation CHAR(12), Team VARCHAR(20), Points INT(3))"

    cursor = mydb.cursor() #create a cursor to execute queries 
    cursor.execute(query)
    print("Table Created!!")
    mydb.close()
except Exception as e:
    mydb.close()
    print(str(e))
```

ERROR:

> True

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rank INT(3), Rider_name CHAR(20), Nation CHAR(12), Team VARCHAR(20), Points INT(' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RANK` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R) in MySQL, well, at least on v8.0.2 and above. If you want to stick with using it, then you have to wrap it in backticks like:

> query = "CREATE TABLE Riders_championship(`Rank` INT(3), Rider_name CHAR(20), Nation CHAR(12), Team VARCHAR(20), Points INT(3))"

And on all your future codes. So doing a `SELECT` like:

```
SELECT Rank FROM Riders_championship;
```

Will return you the same error that you're getting now, therefore you have to write it like:

```
SELECT `Rank` FROM Riders_championship;
```

for it to work. Same goes for all your `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` queries.

Here's a [simple demo to show you](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af46d97b807a450b97cb6d7239bcb882).

I personally won't prefer using keywords even if it's reserved or not so if it's me, I might rename my column to `RANKS` instead. That way it won't clash with the reserved keyword.

Comment: Thank you so much @FaNo_FN  both the options worked! previously I was searching for reserved keywords but i was unable to find "RANK". "RANK" is added in 8.0.2 version.